# Quest: The Golden Claw how to open portcullis

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

In the golden claw quest there are 3 rotating pillars.  I think I have to set them to something for the lever to open the portcullis but I don't know what the combination should be.  Is there a clue I'm missing?

Comment: I was about to take a screenshot, but they started spinning before I managed to.

Comment: Same quest, different door. Sorry! Post reopened.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three runed tablets in the room - you can see one of them which has fallen by the lever at the right of your screenshot, the snake. The other two are above the portcullis.

Duplicate the pattern on those tablets by rotating the pillars, and pulling the level will cause the gate to open (instead of rain painful death on you).